# save value of select form to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, select

I want to insert the value of a selected 'select form' into my mysql database
this 'select from' is connected to database too

```
<label>Kategori</label>
   <select class="form-control">
     <?php include "config.php";
         $kat = mysql_query("select * from kategori order by kode_kategori");

           while ($hasil = mysql_fetch_array($kat)){
              echo "<option value = '$hasil[kode_kategori]'>$hasil[nama_kategori]</option>";
           }
?> 
   </select>
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: have you tried for insertion ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, learn SQL. Learn the basics

To insert something into something, here is the syntax

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ('username', 'password') VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]');";
```

Comment: is the value automatically saved? or i have to add some codes?

Comment: That is the syntax on how to do it. Change the table name to yours, and the username and password to your columns. If you used post, fix it with what u out in post

Comment: If you are trying to insert values 7 and 8 into columns hello and bye, then you would do $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ('hello', 'bye') VALUES (7, 8);";

Answer (score 0):

You can insert value in database like below code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){

     $insert_value = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable ('Column name1', 'Colum name2' , 'Column name3') VALUES ('$_POST['file_name1']', '$_POST['filed_name2']','$_POST['filed_name3']'");

     if($insert_value){
        echo "value insert successfully..."
     }
     else{
        echo "error while insert data.."
     }
  }
?>
```